# Recovering tweets text with message id from R

Tags: r, twitter

According to Twitter API terms of use, tweets collections can be only released if text and user information is removed. So, those collections usually include the message id and the user id.

How can the tweet text be recovered when the message id and the user id are available and we are using the twitteR or streamR R packages?

Thank you.

Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`twitteR::showStatus(id)`?

```
> showStatus(id=413669611599458304)
[1] "LukeAnker: Email marketing blog chart/s (subscribers according to http://t.co/pgk6LpqF0U &lt;3): http://t.co/RrKiQJqdve"
Warning message:
In showStatus(id = 413669611599458304, cainfo = "cacert.pem") :
  Using numeric id value can lead to unexpected results for very large ids
```